# SQL delete all rows except some ones

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the following columns (of urls):

```
 [id,url,visited,timestamp]
 Types:[int,string,int,long]
```

I want to:

Delete all urls except 10 unvisited priorizing higher timestamp (or delete all if all are visited for example)

Its posible to do that in a single query? Anyway whats the best query (queries) for doing it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question, +1. 10 remaining in delete query is tricky to me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think TOP works in sqlite  -- need to use LIMIT

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN ( 
   SELECT id FROM mytable  
   WHERE visited = false 
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC
   LIMIT 10  
   )
```

Comment: Won't this delete 10 records max? The OP wants to delete all *but* 10

Comment: @Shredder: No, the `WHERE` clause is `id NOT IN (...)` and the subquery selects the 10 rows to keep -- so this query will remove all of the others.

Answer (score 7):

```
DELETE FROM tableofDeletion
WHERE
  -- Delete all items not in the following select
  -- ordered by the timestamp so we can get the top 10 
  id NOT IN (SELECT id 
             FROM tableofDeletion
             WHERE 
                 visited = 0 -- false
             ORDER BY timestamp DESC
             LIMIT 10)
```

I think this delivers what you're looking for.

Comment: You don't even need the `visited = true`, sqlite uses LIMIT and not TOP, and there isn't an "unvisited" field ;)